# Floating Numbers in Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

What could be the answer to

${\displaystyle {\binom {2.5}{2}}}$

is it defined or considered as $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma(x)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner not really

Comment: can you provide a reference calculation?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial+coefficient+%282.345+1.234%29

Comment: @sai-kartik: No need for the gamma function. Just use $\binom{a}{k}=\frac{a^{\underline{k}}}{k!}$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer could use the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):

$$\binom {2.5} 2=\dfrac{2.5!}{0.5!\times2!}=\dfrac{\Gamma(3.5)}{\Gamma(1.5)2}=\dfrac{2.5\times1.5}2=1.875.$$

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing $n!=n\cdot(n-1)!$ to fractional numbers,

$$\frac{2.5!}{2!}=\frac{2.5\cdot1.5\cdot0.5!}{2\cdot0.5!}=\frac{15}8.$$

Answer (score 1):

It's called Generalized Binomial Coefficient. For any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\binom{\alpha}{2} = \frac{\alpha!}{(\alpha-2)!2!} = \alpha(\alpha-1) \frac{1}{2!} = (2.5)(1.5)\frac{1}{2!} = \frac{15}{8}
$$
Note this also works for $\alpha <0$.

Comment: But 0 is never attained if $\alpha$ is not a natural number!

Comment: @saulspatz apologies, I fixed that earlier

Comment: @Alex No problem.  It's sometimes hard to figure out the comments if you join the discussion late..

Answer (score 0):

The generalised binomial coefficient $\binom{x}{k}$ ($x\in\mathbf R,\:k\in\mathbf N$) is
$$\binom xk=\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-k+1)}{k!}.$$